# angularJs animate ng-repeat entrance

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, jquery-animate, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've got this simple list of countries and I'm trying to get them to animate on entrance but I can't seem to find what's stopping this from working?

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="country in countries" type="country" class="slide">
       <a ui-sref="state5"> {{country.name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

css file:

```
.slide.ng-enter {
    transition:0.5s linear all;
    transform:translateY(-100px);
}
.slide.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    transform:translateY(0);
}
```

animate.js file:

```
countryApp.animation('.slide', [
        function() {
            return {
                enter: function(element, doneFn) {
                    jQuery(element).slideIn(1000, doneFn);
                }
            }
        }]
```

Can someone perhaps clarify this for me? Thanks

Comment: which browser are you testing??

Comment: @JqueryKing I'm using chrome

Answer (score 0):

your css style only working for firefox. if you want chrome use `-webkit` prefix

```
.slide.ng-enter {
    transition:0.5s linear all;
    transform:translateY(-100px);
    -webkit-transition:0.5s linear all;
    -webkit-transform:translateY(-100px);
}
.slide.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    transform:translateY(0);
    -webkit-transform:translateY(0);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've used your method instead but I'm still having an issue. Could it be something wrong with the way the animation is being called?

Comment: @tryingtolearn - I don't know really what is an issue again you faced. If you get some ideas from my answer means mark it as accept and upvote you can. basically i am jquery person I am also newbie in angular thanks for your understanding